# determine if MKMapView was dragged or zoomed

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I just need a way to differentiate between this 2 events while playing with the map:

1. dragging the mapview
2. zooming the mapview

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MKMapView` is not based on `UIScrollView` so it doesn't call `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods. But nonetheless, you can instantiate `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`, add them to your map view and work with their action methods.

Answer (score 3):

inside MKMapView delegate methods:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView region{Will,Did}ChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

compare the "new" span with the "old" one. Something like

```
MKZoomScale currentZoomScale = (CGFloat)(map.bounds.size.width / map.visibleMapRect.size.width);
```

in the BreadCrumb Sample Project.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Listings/Classes_BreadcrumbViewController_m.html